# Binary Gaussian Elimination of a matrix

Tags: binary, gaussian-elimination

Can anyone help me find the algorithm for the Binary Gaussian elimination of a  matrix.

*for example:*

[image]

*The output:*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This could help you:

https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/factoring/fastgauss.pdf

It is analytical.